# jquery progress bar

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i am using this progress bar from [jspprogresshandler](http://www.bram.us/demo/projects/jsprogressbarhandler/) and now i want to do a modification in the progress.

i want to display mutiple values in the bar.supposing the total of the bar is 100% so now i want to display 20,30,10,40 in diffrent colours making a some upto 100.
now here that static values that i mentioned is not the only ones,i want thos to be handeled dynamically

i would love it if anybody would advice how to incorporate ajax along with this

thanx in advance

Comment: And what does Ajax have to do with this?

Comment: the data for the bar will be changing any moment and the changes have to be reflected on the bar.so thats the reason thought of using ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this - http://www.bram.us/demo/projects/jsprogressbarhandler/ajaxprogressbar.html.

Comment: Why can't grab it. It's plain HTML. Just right mouse click and 'View Source'.